# handle lines in region or not

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have `N` lines with code like this:

```
let aafdafa
let bfaf
let cb
```

I want translate this code to this:

```
let aafdafa = aafdafa.len();
let bfaf = bfaf.len();
let cb = cb.len();
```

`replace-regexp` not work with selection,
how should I solve this task in `emacs`?

Comment: Magnar's `multiple-cursors` could handle that if you only have a couple of thousand or less lines that need to be selected.  Have a look at the Emacs Rocks video.  Select multiple lines starting from the left margin, jump over let and the space using something like forward word, hold the shift key down and and then select to end of line, press the copy command, then space = space, then paste then type .len(); and then return key to exit.  See also my proposed fix to speed up selecting multiple lines:  https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el/issues/279

Comment: I've never understood why everything has to be solved in emacs. If you have `sed` (either on linux or with something like cygwin on Windows), this is a one liner: `sed 'N1,N2s/let \(.*\)/let \1 = \1.len();/' <file>` where N1 is the number of the first line and N2 is the number of the last line of the region that you want to transform in the file. Emacs is great but there *are* other tools too.

Comment: @Nick Because of number of actions. If I use your advise: I have to select suitable lines, put them into new buffer, save buffer to file, exec `sed` and put stuff back. In that case no need for sed, I can just copy/paste to `*scratch*` and call `replace-regexp`, less keyboard press.

Comment: It really depends on the specific circumstances (which I of course don't know): are the lines you want to change contiguous in the buffer or scattered randomly? How many lines do you have to change? If it is a handful, then changing one and cutting and pasting might be faster than defining a macro; etc. etc.  However, I have seen many cases in the past, where an emacs solution is sought, while a simple combination of tools can do the job much more easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a task for an Emacs Macro: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros

Macros are built-in powerful features to record and repeat key strokes. You could:

1. Go to the beginning of the line
2. Jump one word (to the var) and yank it
3. Add an `=`
4. Paste the var
5. Add `.len();`

And then repeat n times.

Answer (score 2):

`replace-regexp` does work with a region.  Even if it didn't, you can set the region and do `narrow-to-region` and operate on the narrowed buffer.  Anyway, the regexp should be something like `let \(.+\)` -> `\& = \1.len()`, where `\&` means the entire match and `\1` means the first group.